# Plaid - Update mode vs re-linking account

Tags: plaid

I have been trying to use update mode to correct for `"error_code":"ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED"`. Plaid I'm currently working off the Quickstart. My current issue is that I get this error, I will reauthenticate the account via Link in the Quickstart app. I'll get a new access_token from that, which will work for a few hours until the error comes back up (even though I'm not updating security details on the bank side, or using persistent OTP).

If I don't care about maintaining the same access_token, what is the big difference between update mode and getting a new access token by re-linking the account? Will update mode prevent the error from happening again?

For context, I am pretty new to working with the plaid API and have been trouble getting update mode to work. I've been able to launch Link in update mode by modifying the quickstart code. It launches and recognizes the bank from the access_token, but will tell me my credentials are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons to want to keep the same access token (such as avoiding duplicate billing, or being able to use persistent `account_id` identifiers to track the same accounts -- trying to build a personal finance manager app with a new access token every few hours would be a nightmare because you wouldn't be able to track the state of transactions as they posted). Depending on your use case, these reasons may or may not matter to you.

I doubt update mode would fix your problem -- it seems likely that whatever is causing this issue would also happen after update mode and is also the reason that update mode isn't working for you in the first place.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your response. Totally hear you on why I'd want to keep the same access_token, but for now I'm just trying to keep the data flow alive so I was hoping that update mode would make a difference. I actually managed to get update mode working, but you're right that I'm still running into the same issue. I've opened a support ticket!